# Warnings after update Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, publickeytoken

I just updated Xamarin Studio to the latest version (Xamarin.Android
Version: 4.6.4 (Business Edition)) and I'm receiving a lot of warnings after the update..:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
> Warning: Reference 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' not resolved (TrackandTrace.Droid)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
> Warning: Reference 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=xxxx' not resolved (TrackandTrace.Droid)

I already tried to remove the reference and re-add it without any effect.

**Update:**
Even if i create a new project I receive 2 errors right from the start.. These errors make unable to build android projects.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Are you worried that your code won't compile or are you just worried about the warnings?

Comment: @Bryan I'm just worried about the warnings. Where do they come from? how do I fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced that after upgrading(I believe you tried in release mode)
try to change your appropriate architectures in your applications properties (if not sure, select all 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try following (only a guess):

Find following Path:
`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104\SupportedFrameworks`

In that directory add a new xml file with that name: "`MonoAndroid, Version=v1.6+.xml`". And the following Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Framework DisplayName="Mono for Android"
  Identifier="MonoAndroid"
  Profile="*"
  MinimumVersion="1.6"
  MaximumVersion="*" />
```

Restart Visual Studio and try it again.

Comment: As you can read in the title im using Xamarin Studio and im using a Mac.. Do you know the link for mac?.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried updating a couple of weeks ago.  Some useful advice I got from the support/bug fixing team:

Inside Xamarin Studio, click Help-->Check for Updates.  Change the update channel from Stable to Alpha (or Beta) and try that version.  If that doesn't work, you can roll back to a previous version by going to:

http://store.xamarin.com/account/Products and clicking on Show Recent Releases on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core NuGet package to your core project and that should fix the issue.

See ["Can not resolve reference: `System.Memory`" or "Could not find `System.Memory`" after update to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296773/can-not-resolve-reference-system-memory-or-could-not-find-system-memory) for details.