# xamarin conflicts with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

I want to use entity framework in my xamarin.forms solution, but when I install the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" nugget package I face with this build error:

> Can not resolve reference: `System.Buffers`, referenced by `System.Memory`.
>   Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Buffers`, or remove > the reference to `System.Memory`.

**Error screenshot:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yr82.png]

how can I handle this error? if can not handle this error, how I can use entity framework with xamarin.forms?
or is there any alternative solution to entity framework?

I have visual studio 15.8.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite v2.1.2, both of them are the latest version.

thank you so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296773/can-not-resolve-reference-system-memory-or-could-not-find-system-memory

Comment: @SushiHangover: I do not have any "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" package, my problem occurs when I install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" nugget package, I have visual studio 15.8.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite v2.1.2, both of them are the latest version

Comment: Same root problem, read that answer to the end...

Comment: @SushiHangover thank u so much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" package and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

try install-package System.Buffers in same project of EF, worked for me.